# When do questions become too broad?

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

So I hopped in the close vote queue today and found [this gem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057338/understanding-execute-async-script-in-selenium)  Apparently it was an audit and I failed because I voted to close as too broad.  The post looks good except for the question.  It is asking about when to use an async javascript doohiky instead of the synchronous version.  I felt that answers would have to be "too broad" to explain the difference effectively.  To quote the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions):

> too broad - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or
>   has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format

I can imagine the docs for that particular method has a page on that function.  (Also, [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) came up via google.  I can imagine a lengthy discussion involving differences between the two functions based off that alone).  Also, debating when to do something asynchronously vs. synchronously is something I've seen some co-workers talk about for quite some time.

Bottom line: I'm not concerned that I failed the audit.  What I want to know is:

1. Is my reasoning OK?
2. If not, where did I go wrong so I can get it right in the future?

Comment: The question could be answered by an entire book, but it doesn't have to be. Explaining the difference between an async call and a sync call is a sufficient answer. The question, "When is x - y > 0?" can be answered with an unlimited number of number combinations, or with the simple statement "When x > y". Specifically, this is asking about something they don't understand as part of a library. The answer regarding its purpose can definitely be written a paragraph.

Comment: @Compass Does the fact that a question _could_ be answered with a paragraph save it from being closed?  For example doing a quick search on SO I found [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js) (Closed as not constructive but would probably be closed as too broad today).  I could go to the node.js site and copy their one paragraph description of what node is  and use a couple sentences to address the rest of the question.  (Just an example, I'm sure I could find other / better examples given time.)  If the question should stand, where do we draw the line?

Comment: The author is asking for a distinction between two methods. It falls in the similar category as differentiating between slice and substr: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243824/what-is-the-difference-between-string-slice-and-string-substring One can certainly list all unique cases where slice would be more practical to use than substring or substr, but a sufficient explanation is explaining what the two methods are for. Consider the scope of the question. "What is Java" is broad. "What is Java's ternary operator" not so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some types of A/B or multiple-choice questions are perfectly fine on Stack Overflow.  They don't have to be completely devoid of subjectivity; they just have to be informative.  They don't always have to have one correct answer; few things in computing do.

Example of a good question:

> [This language feature] was added to [my favorite programming language], and I can see how it might be useful, but the language already had [this other language feature] that does the same thing.  What is the difference, and when would I use one over the other?

Example of a bad question:

> Which language is better?

Can you see the difference?  The first one is answerable in a few paragraphs; the second one isn't.

Comment: That totally makes sense.  I'm not sure what I was thinking.  Chalking this one up to not enough sleep / caffeine.